# STM32f GPIO's on 1.8V

Tags: stm32, gpio, stm32f4

So I'm trying to figure out what GPIO voltage levels on an STM32F4 would if I have my VDD at 1.8V. I'm assuming you just use the minimum values, however the conditions state 2.7V < Vdd < 3.6V, that means either the conditions were only tested for that voltage range OR they only hold for that range. There isn't any other info in the datasheet on Voh and 1.8V

In previous digital devices, I've seen differences between the different voltages (like 2.4v and 3.6V). So for 2.4V it would be Vdd-0.2 and for 3.3V it would be Vdd-0.4.

You can run this chip at 1.8V, that's stated elsewhere in the datasheet. Under table 6.3.1

> VDD: Standard operating voltage 1.7V - 3.6V

What is my minimum Voh and max Vol range for CMOS on an I/O Pin if my Vdd is 1.8?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out what GPIO voltage levels on an STM32F4 would if I have my VDD at 1.8V.
>
> What is my minimum Voh and max Vol range for CMOS on an I/O Pin if my Vdd is 1.8?

The table which you kindly included, might suggest that it was for a device which was only supported down to V<sub>DD</sub> = 2 V (i.e. the lowest voltage mentioned in *that* table).

However the [datasheet for the STM32F437](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f437vg.pdf) gives these V<sub>OL</sub> and V<sub>OH</sub> figures below, which specifically include V<sub>DD</sub> = 1.8 V as you asked:

---

[image: extract from STM32F437 datasheet]

---

Comment: Thats what it suggests, if you read the *rest* of the datasheet, it shows a spec for Vdd which reads 1.7V for the lowest value and 3.6V for the highest value. That is listed under "Standard Operating Voltage" so its not an absolute maximum rating. ***Yes you can run this at 1.8V***. The absolute maximum table also shows the FT pins (general I/O) being able to run at that voltage.

Comment: @laptop2d - OK, so the "odd one out" in *your* STM32F4 datasheet seems to be the "Output voltage characteristics" table, since you have that other evidence that your STM32F4 MCU can run down to 1.7V (same as the STM32F437). Since some specs are common to all the STM32F4 family, I would start by expecting that the numbers which I quoted from the STM32F437 datasheet, *probably* apply to your version too. Of course a *definitive* answer can only come from ST. Perhaps there's an updated version of whichever datasheet you are reading, or perhaps you are the first person to notice the mistake?